# Template Expression Doesn't allow for Computer Expression in lightning-input-field

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield, template

I have been trying to iterate through and access some data that I'm getting from an apex call.
I have a list of field IDs that I get from a field set something like
`this.positionFieldIds=['Name', 'Id', 'Contacts']`

While my records are something like

```
[{recordTypeId:'000', fields:{'Name':{displayValue:'Placeholder', value:'5'}, 'Id':{displayValue:'Placeholder', value:'5'}, 'Contacts':{displayValue:'Placeholder', value:'2345'}}
```

I was trying to access the value and prepopulate my form with values that I get from a wire call, but I was getting the

`Template Expression Doesn't allow for Computer Expression in lightning-input-field` error message and I wasn't sure how to populate the template accurately.

```
<template for:each={positionRecords} for:item="rec" for:index="index">
<lightning-record-edit-form key={rec.id} object-api-name="Account">
   <template for:each={positionFieldIds} for:item="field">
     <lightning-layout-item key={field}>
     <lightning-input-field field-name={field} variant="label-stacked" value={rec.fields[field].value}></lightning-input-field>
     </lightning-layout-item>
   </template>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the attribute expression `value={rec.fields[field].value}`.

What you need to do is shift the expression handling into your JavaScript so you have a simple array of tuples to iterate, something like:

```
this.fields = Object.keys(this.rec.fields).
    map(key => {
      return {
               name: key,
               value: this.rec.fields[key].value
             }; 
    });
```

You need to do this when you get your record back.

You can then simply iterate the `this.fields` array and access the `name` and `value` properties in the template, something like:

```
<template for:each={fields} for:item="field">
  <lightning-layout-item key={field.name}>
  <lightning-input-field field-name={field.name} variant="label-stacked" value={field.value}></lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
</template>
```